# How to output < in JSPX without it being interpreted by the browser

Tags: jspx

I am writing an html hint sheet in .JSPX and I want user to see

```
<b>
```

So, I write

```
&#60;b&#62;
```

OR

```
&lt;b&gt;
```

but both of these produce

```
<b>
```

as their output to the browser and everything afterwards goes bold.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSPX parser is processing your entity.
You need to escape the `&` to prevent that: `&amp;lt;`

Comment: Is this a standard way of doing this type of thing in JSPX, or is there something not properly configured on my side?

Comment: @AlexParansky: I don't really know JSPX, but this is the only way to do it if you want to use valid XML.

Comment: @AlexParansky As far as I know, this is the standard way to do it.